# How to convert this data into time series for arima model forecasting

Tags: r

```
 s
      X   Jan   Feb   Mar   Apr   May   Jun   Jul   Aug   Sep   Oct Nov   Dec
1  2012 24.78 26.82 29.75 31.19 31.87 31.00 28.48 27.39 27.08 26.55 24.36 23.62
2  2013 24.82 26.04 28.83 30.85 32.44 29.70 27.86 27.66 27.73 27.00 24.87 22.94
3  2014 24.01 25.75 29.08 31.83 31.23 33.08 29.88 28.14 27.40 27.11 25.38 24.37
4  2015 24.60 26.11 29.19 30.71 32.69 28.90 29.21 28.24 27.58 27.82 25.37 24.71
5  2016 25.20 27.62 29.51 31.86 32.34 28.64 27.98 28.36 27.12 26.51 25.69 25.12
6  2017 25.28 26.88 29.55 31.88 32.74 29.89 28.41 27.60 27.72 27.23 25.43 24.08
7  2018 24.84 26.47 29.40 31.20 31.10 30.28 28.30 27.33 27.55 27.40 26.98 24.77
8  2019 23.73 26.75 29.57 31.59 32.53 31.30 29.48 27.78 27.54 27.05 25.44 24.46
9  2020 25.41 26.75 29.30 31.37 32.98 30.05 28.23 27.53 27.68 27.01 25.57 22.86
10 2021 24.70 25.90 29.62 31.42 31.68 30.17 28.13 28.08 27.68 27.29 25.59 23.16
```

How to convert this into time series for forecasting?

Comment: And the question is?

Comment: Questions posted should have reproducible input using `dput(s)`.  I have created that for you in the Note at the end of my answer but next time please follow the instructions at the top of [tag:r} tag page when posting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `pivot_longer()` function from the `tidyr` package to convert this into a longer format. Then the `ts()` function can covert it to a timeseries.

```
# recreate the original data
data1 <- structure(list(X=c(2012,2013,2014,2015,2016,2017,2018,2019,2020,2021),
               Jan=c(24.78,24.82,24.01,24.6,25.2,25.28,24.84,23.73,25.41,24.7),
               Feb=c(26.82,26.04,25.75,26.11,27.62,26.88,26.47,26.75,26.75,25.9),
               Mar=c(29.75,28.83,29.08,29.19,29.51,29.55,29.4,29.57,29.3,29.62),
               Apr=c(31.19,30.85,31.83,30.71,31.86,31.88,31.2,31.59,31.37,31.42),
               May=c(31.87,32.44,31.23,32.69,32.34,32.74,31.1,32.53,32.98,31.68),
               Jun=c(31,29.7,33.08,28.9,28.64,29.89,30.28,31.3,30.05,30.17),
               Jul=c(28.48,27.86,29.88,29.21,27.98,28.41,28.3,29.48,28.23,28.13),
               Aug=c(27.39,27.66,28.14,28.24,28.36,27.6,27.33,27.78,27.53,28.08),
               Sep=c(27.08,27.73,27.4,27.58,27.12,27.72,27.55,27.54,27.68,27.68),
               Oc=c(26.55,27,27.11,27.82,26.51,27.23,27.4,27.05,27.01,27.29),
               Nov=c(24.36,24.87,25.38,25.37,25.69,25.43,26.98,25.44,25.57,25.59),
               Dec=c(23.62,22.94,24.37,24.71,25.12,24.08,24.77,24.46,22.86,23.16)),
          row.names=c(NA,-10L),
          class=c("tbl_df","tbl","data.frame"))

# pivot to longer format
library(tidyr)
data2 <- pivot_longer(data1,-X,values_to='value')

# convert to monthly timeseries starting at Jan 2012 ending at Dec 2021
timeseries <- ts(data2$value,start=2012,end=2021+11/12,frequency=12)
```

Answer (score 0):

We assume that the question is how to convert a data frame in the form of the data shown in the Note at the end of this answer to a ts object.  In particular we assume that the only NA's are at the beginning in case it does not start in January and/or at the end if it does not end in December.  We also show how to easily remove that assumption.

**1)** This alternative is only one line of code. After removing the year column transpose it using `t`, unravel that into a vector using `c` and then specify the appropriate start year, `s[1, 1]`, and the frequency of 12.  We assume that if it does not start in January or end in December that it starts and/or ends with NA's so remove them with `na.omit` -- if we knew it starts in January and ends in December we could optionally remove the `na.omit` in the code below.  No packages are used.

(If there were also NA's internally then use `na.trim` from zoo package in place of `na.omit` .)

```
na.omit(ts(c(t(s[, -1])), start = s[1, 1], frequency = 12))
```

**2)** An alternative approach is to convert the input `s` to a zoo object and then use `as.ts` .   First convert `s` to a 12 column zoo object using `read.zoo` and then melt it to a long data frame having columns corresponding to the year, month and value.  We read that into a zoo object with yearmon index and trim.  Finally convert that to a ts object.  Although longer, this one avoids dealing with the start value and frequency explicitly and works well with pipes.  We could omit the `na.trim` step if we knew that the series started in January and ended in December.

```
library(zoo)

# given a data frame, x, with year in first column and abbreviated
#   month in second column return a yearmon object
to_ym <- function(x) as.yearmon(paste(x[[1]], x[[2]]), "%Y %b")

s |>
  read.zoo() |>
  fortify.zoo(melt = TRUE) |>
  read.zoo(index = 1:2, FUN = to_ym) |>
  na.trim() |>
  as.ts()
```

### Note

```
s <- structure(list(X = 2012:2021, Jan = c(24.78, 24.82, 24.01, 24.6, 
25.2, 25.28, 24.84, 23.73, 25.41, 24.7), Feb = c(26.82, 26.04, 
25.75, 26.11, 27.62, 26.88, 26.47, 26.75, 26.75, 25.9), Mar = c(29.75, 
28.83, 29.08, 29.19, 29.51, 29.55, 29.4, 29.57, 29.3, 29.62), 
    Apr = c(31.19, 30.85, 31.83, 30.71, 31.86, 31.88, 31.2, 31.59, 
    31.37, 31.42), May = c(31.87, 32.44, 31.23, 32.69, 32.34, 
    32.74, 31.1, 32.53, 32.98, 31.68), Jun = c(31, 29.7, 33.08, 
    28.9, 28.64, 29.89, 30.28, 31.3, 30.05, 30.17), Jul = c(28.48, 
    27.86, 29.88, 29.21, 27.98, 28.41, 28.3, 29.48, 28.23, 28.13
    ), Aug = c(27.39, 27.66, 28.14, 28.24, 28.36, 27.6, 27.33, 
    27.78, 27.53, 28.08), Sep = c(27.08, 27.73, 27.4, 27.58, 
    27.12, 27.72, 27.55, 27.54, 27.68, 27.68), Oct = c(26.55, 
    27, 27.11, 27.82, 26.51, 27.23, 27.4, 27.05, 27.01, 27.29
    ), Nov = c(24.36, 24.87, 25.38, 25.37, 25.69, 25.43, 26.98, 
    25.44, 25.57, 25.59), Dec = c(23.62, 22.94, 24.37, 24.71, 
    25.12, 24.08, 24.77, 24.46, 22.86, 23.16)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", 
"2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"))
```